# STM32F4 external interrupt is not working after jump to application

Tags: iar, stm32f4

I have written boot-loader code to jump from 0x08000000 to 0x08008000 and it's jumping to application. In application PA10 is configure as a external signal interrupt on falling edge, external interrupt is not coming when I am jumping from bootloader. When I loaded my application directly without any bootloader at address 0x8000000, then I am getting interrupt.
External pin interrupt is not coming when I am using bootloader. I have verify my ISR it is in address 0x8008000 in flash.

bootloader code : sudo code

```
HAL_Init();       
SystemClock_Config();  
MX_GPIO_Init();
appEntry = (pFunction) *(__IO uint32_t*) (APPLICATION_ADDRESS + 4);

    HAL_UART_DeInit(&huart1);
    HAL_DeInit();
    HAL_RCC_DeInit();

    HAL_SuspendTick();


    systemReset();  
    SCB->VTOR = 0x8008000;
    __set_MSP(appStack);
```